# How do you use JavaScript to dynamically change properties based upon window width and scroll amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Document paragraph tags should change color dynamically according to browser width, 1023px, and scroll amount, 120px. What happens:

No default background color is loading.
As soon as you scroll the scrolling change works.
To get the window width change you have to resize the window then reload the page.

You can see the demo page at [scroll+width.html](https://dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/scroll+width.html)

The jQuery library is loaded. Here is the code for the 4 states:

```
<style type='text/css'>
.swap-to-blue {
background: blue;
color: white;
}
.swap-to-red {
background: red;
color: white;
}
.swap-to-green {
background: green;
color: white;
}
.swap-to-purple {
background: purple;
color: white;
}
.swapout {
background: white;
color: black;
}

</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    function setDefaults() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {

      if( $(window).scrollTop() <= 120 && $(document).width() > 1023 ) 
            {
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-purple');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-green');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-blue');
        $('p').addClass('swap-to-red');
        // $('p').removeClass('swapout');
            }

      if( $(window).scrollTop() > 120 && $(document).width() > 1023 ) 
            {
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-red');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-green');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-purple');
        $('p').addClass('swap-to-blue');
        // $('p').removeClass('swapout');
            }

      if( $(window).scrollTop() <= 120 && $(document).width() <= 1023 ) 
            {
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-red');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-blue');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-green');
        $('p').addClass('swap-to-purple');
        // $('p').addClass('swapout');
      }

      if( $(window).scrollTop() > 120 && $(document).width() <= 1023 ) 
            {
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-blue');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-red');
        $('p').removeClass('swap-to-purple');
        $('p').addClass('swap-to-green');
        // $('p').addClass('swapout');
      }

        });
    }

    setDefaults(); // Execute on load
    $(window).resize(setDefaults); // Bind event listener

    });

</script>
```

Comment: ok, defining the width based classes should be done with media queries, then you only have 2 groups to switch between is scrollTop > 120 or not

Comment: Tip: you should select the element only once not several times`let p = $('p');`

Comment: Robert, thx for the tip however my javascript skill are rather basic; I would need to see an example within the context of the code I grabbed how to do this.

Comment: Lawrence, yes I agree that is how you would typically manage this problem, however  doing it that way did not work in the scenario in hand. Although I set up media queries it was not honoring the need if I squeezed and widened the browser unless I reloaded the page. It may not be normal for viewers to squeeze a browser on a larger device to under 768px - but it can happen. The other thing, I really want to have this function in my back pocket for any reason down the road.